# Fancy border Divider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following (notice the 1 pixel gap at either end):

[image: Fancy Divider]

Comment: do you want the border to be complete ie a square or a rectangle or is this just a top or bottom of a border?

Comment: Any extra points for a non-image CSS solution?

Comment: @davidb top and bottom, but can be any width... To be honest, I will just stick with `background-image` I think. It is very easy and it is not exactly a big image, especially if I include it in a sprite...

Comment: @MarcAudet That is exactly what I am looking for, some way of achieving this without images, but I fear that is not possible...

Comment: Have no fear! check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try:

```
<hr class="fancy">
```

with the following CSS:

```
hr.fancy {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    color: black;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
hr.fancy:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 7px;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
hr.fancy:before {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 7px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/P7umD/

You can play with the pixel widths to get a bolder look.

**Browser Compatibility**
I checked this in Firefox and Chrome and the mark-up renders consistently.

However, does not work in IE9, you only get the double lines and not the book-ends.

Comment: @Johan Which browser are you using? I only checked FF.

Comment: @Johan I made some tweaks to the CSS and it now renders correctly in Chrome.

Comment: I am tweaking it a bit to get it to work for IE9, but will have to work on it later.  Thank you! However, it is an interesting technique.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `border-image` will do the trick

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Or you can use a `div` based solution

```
<div class="border">
    Content

    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>



.border {
    border-width:0px;
    border-style: double;
    border-color: grey;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    position: relative;
}
.left,
.right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: -3px;
    background-color: white;
}
.left {
    left: 1px;
}
.right {
    right: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zCEKp/

Comment: If I am going to use an image, I might as well just use `background-image`. But thank you anyway for the first valid answer :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="top-left"></div>
        <div class="top-right"></div>
        <div class="bottom-left"></div>
        <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    position:relative;
    border:3px double;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
.top-left, .top-right, .bottom-left, .bottom-right {
    position:absolute;
    width:4px;
    height:4px;
    border-left:1px #fff solid;
    border-right:1px #fff solid;
}
.top-left, .top-right{
    top:-4px;
}
.top-left, .bottom-left{
    left:-4px;
}
.top-right, .bottom-right{
    right:-4px;
}
.bottom-left, .bottom-right {
    bottom:-4px;
}
```

[Here's jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/H3rwr/1/)

Comment: Did you see the 1 pixel gap?

Comment: Thank you for correcting. I appreciate your time, but I am more than capable of achieving the border this way, what I really wanted was a cool CSS trick to do with without a load of nested divs... See Marc's answer

Comment: I misunderstood your question 2 times in a row. (c-c-c-combo) I thought you need a border to be on every side of an element with gaps on top and bottom sides only, not a separator. Glad you've found a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

This css-only solution may work for you:

html markup:

```
<div class="fancydivider">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="middle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fancydivider {
    clear: both;
}
    .fancydivider .left {
        border-bottom: double black;
        width: 1px;
        float: left;
    }
    .fancydivider .middle {
        border-bottom: double black;
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
    }
    .fancydivider .right {
        border-bottom: double black;
        width: 1px;
        float: left;
    }
```

result:

<s>http://jsfiddle.net/KNqR8/</s>

http://jsfiddle.net/Lucidus/ZjGpS/1/ 
[edit: wrong css in first link - I don't know what happened ;-)]

[image]